# FreeBSD 11 not recognising changes to connected devices when MTP device attached to USB. Phone, cable, and USB socket all work

Tags: freebsd, hardware, usb-device

When I connect my phone via USB (USB type C to A cable) to my FreeBSD 11.2 setup, nothing happens. No console messages, nothing in `camcontrol devlist`, `dmesg`, or `usbconfig` AFAICS. (I could be missing something subtle, but I don't see anything).

The phone and cable are reliable (automounting and MTP work fine when connected to my Windows PC). Also, all the USB sockets are reliable on the server (they work fine when I connect my keyboard to them). The system is standard Intel/Supermicro/Xeon.

I know I dont have the `fuse` drivers installed to mount the device, but I gather it should at least be recognised as a raw USB device *somehow*. But it isn't, apparently.

How do I troubleshoot this and fix the device being at least noticed *somehow* when it's connected?

Comment: There should be at least `ugenX:` messages printed. Check your USB port or cable.

Comment: I've checked them. That's what I don't understand. If I plug a USB stick into the same USB port (directly or using the same and cable) it's detected, and if I plug the same phone and cable into Windows it's also detected. That seems to rule out the phone, the cable, and the USB port, as issues? Hence why I'm dead-ended on why I'm not seeing anything, and what to look for, next, to give a hint why.

Comment: Ahh. Now that's really odd. But I think it might be the cable. It bends slightly one way to plug into the PC, slightly the other way for the server. Perhaps a slightly loose connection - when I bend it the other way it now registers on the server. That's why it wasn't showing before.

Comment: You _are_ performing all this as **root**. Right? Group permissions often prevent regular users from access to some devices that may otherwise become available to the system. So [su(1)](https://manpage.me/?su) to at least someone in the `wheel` group. Also there's no harm in issuing `kldload fuse`, or `kldload fusefs` as required. As that will also provide "hints" depending upon what's plugged in. If you're still not seeing messages sent to your screen (pty). [tail(1)](https://manpages/?tail) is your friend `tail -n 15 /var/log/messages` right after plugging/unplugging things in/out.